# I can't create a condition in react to do a validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a problem here in React, I need to make a condition like it is in line 66 and 67, but it does not let me add the one that is in line 68, for when something happens execute one or the other, I need to apply the same condition as onClick product.showPrice.offerPrice> 0

UPDATEEE

I need to apply the same logic that my eventClickOption function has, but in
`{...carouselItem("product_impression", product.id, product.name,  product.category)}`

```
eventClickOption = (product:any) => {
if(product.showPrice.offerPrice > 0 ){
return carouselItem( "click_product_promo", product.id, product.name, 
product.category)
} return carouselItem( "click_product", product.id, product.name, 
product.category)
}


 <div className="body">
      <IonSlides key={this.slideId} id={this.slideId} pager={false}>
        {this.props.products.map(product => ( 
          <IonSlide key={product.id} onClick={this.eventClickOption}
            {...carouselItem("product_impression", product.id, product.name, 
 product.category)} >
            <ProductCard
              key={product.id}
              product={product}
              settings={this.props.settings}
              cartModel={this.props.cartModel}
              onGoToCart={onGoToCart}
            ></ProductCard>
            
          </IonSlide>
        ))}
      </IonSlides>
    </div>
```

I need that if it is greater than 0, to execute

`{... carouselItem ("product_impression_promo", product.id, product.name, this.props.info.title)}` 
and if not
`{... carouselItem ("product_impression", product.id, product.name, this.props.info.title)}`

I tried some ways, but could not solve it as it gave me error

Comment: Is it supposed to display something ? Like your function {... carouselItem ("product_impression_promo", product.id, product.name, this.props.info.title)}, what does it do exactly ? (the answer wouldn't be the same)

Comment: No, it is not a view, it is only a function that sends me those parameters that it has inside, to capture some events in firebase

Comment: So I only need that if the offerPrice is greater than 0, send that a product with promotion was printed, if not, a normal one

Answer (score 2):

you can seprate the logic you need in a function and pass it the the onClick like :

```
const isProductPriceExist =() => {
 if(product.showPrice.offerPrice > 0 ){
     return carouselItem( "click_product_promo", product.id, product.name, product.category)
} return carouselItem( "click_product", product.id, product.name, product.category)
         
}
```

it will be more easy and more readable

```
<IonSlide key={product.id} onClick ={isProductPriceExist} {...carouselItem("product_impression", product.id, product.name, product.category)}/>
```

Comment: Ok, but that is working only with the onClick function, I still have the problem of  {...carouselItem("product_impression", product.id, product.name, product.category)}

Comment: it suppose to work just fine for ex :
`var carsNum = () => [1,2,3]` and you want to pass prop `{...carsNum()}` it will give you the object you need `{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}`

Comment: I think we are not understanding each other, but thanks for your answer

Comment: I need to put the same condition of product.showPrice.offerPrice> 0
but apply it not to the one with click_product as string, nor click_product_promo, I need to apply it to product_impression

Comment: is the onClick event works as expected now ? If not check if it is called in your IonSlides component - your last code : {...carouselItem("product_impression", product.id, product.name, product.category)} returns a list of props you are passing ? Or is it a function you want to execute to execute some logic ? If you are not trying to pass down props but to execute a function with logic it should definitely not be called there

Comment: I only need to send those parameters to a function that is in charge of sending them to firebase, I still can't set the condition for one or the other to be sent the {... carouselItem ("product_impression", product.id, product.name, product. category)}

Comment: Necesito una condicicion que si offerPrice> 0, envie `... carouselItem (" product_impression_promo ", product.id, product.name, product.category)` y si no es mayor a 0, entonces que envie `... carouselItem ( "product_impression", product.id, product.name, product.category) `

Answer (score 0):

My solution was this,

```
  <IonSlides key={this.slideId} id={this.slideId} pager={false}>
        {this.props.products.map(product => {
        if(product && product.showPrice.offerPrice > 0) {
          carouselItem("product_impression_promo", product.id, product.name, product.category)}
        else{
          carouselItem("product_impression", product.id, product.name, product.category)
        }
          return(
          <IonSlide key={product.id} onClick ={()=>product && product.showPrice.offerPrice > 0 ? 
            carouselItem( "click_product_promo", product.id, product.name, product.category) :
              carouselItem( "click_product", product.id, product.name, product.category )}>
            <ProductCard
              key={product.id}
              product={product}
              settings={this.props.settings}
              cartModel={this.props.cartModel}
              onGoToCart={onGoToCart}
            ></ProductCard>
            
          </IonSlide>)
        })}
      </IonSlides>
```

I did the condition above and change the () of the map to {} so that it will take the condition and add a return, and now it works